RSA problem with unconventional calculation of phi
I have $\phi$,$N$ and ciphertext. But the $\phi$ is calculated with $\phi=(p+1)(q+1)$. I normally calculate $d$ but cannot recover the message.

Obviously $ϕ$ is not the Euler totient for $pq$ (with positive $p$ and $q$). Please tell the parity of $ϕ$ and $N$, and the approximate value of $(ϕ/N)-1$, including sign.

Or, is this a CTF challenge (where they give you a $\phi'$ which isn't the real $\phi$, but a value that you might be able to use to compute the correct one?

I think it is CTF, and @poncho is right.

You haven't given much context so I'll try my best to answer your question.
We denote the Euler totient by $\varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$ and  $\phi(n) = (p+1)(q+1)$.
Using $\phi(n)=(p+1)(q+1)$ impacts the correctness of the RSA scheme.
The proper way of calculating the Euler totient is : $\varphi(n)=\varphi(p)\varphi(q)=(p-1)*(q-1)$
This formula ensures the correctness. Indeed, given the modulus $n$, a message $m$ and its associated cipher $c$ : $c^d=m^{ed}=m^{k*\varphi(n)+1} \mod{n}$, for some integer k.
Thanks to little Fermat's theorem : $m^{k*\varphi(n)+1} = 1^km^1 = m \mod{n}$.
However, using the formula $\phi(n)=(p+1)(q+1)$ make the decryption go  wrong :
I assumed the key generation to be the usual textbook version of RSA with the unusual phi formula i.e wrong implementation.
Let's recall that $ed = 1 \mod{\phi(n)},$
So, $c^d = m^{ed} = m^{\phi(n)k +1} = m^{k(p+1)(q+1)+1} \mod{n}$ for some integer $k$, which can't be simpified to $m$.
Let's solve the problem :
Notice that $p+q = \phi(n) -n -1 = C$
So we have:
$$ \begin{cases}
C = p+q\\
n= pq\\
\end{cases} $$
So $n = p(C-p) = -p^2 + pC$. This is a a quadratic equation $x^2 -xC + n = 0$. $\Delta = C^2 - 4n = (p+q)^2 - 4n >0$. Then this equation has two solutions in $\mathbb{R}$. Let's see if these solutions are integers.
$$ \begin{cases}
r_1 = \frac{C-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\\
r_2 = \frac{C+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}
\end{cases} $$
It turns out that these two solutions are $p$ and $q$. We can now calculate the proper $\varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$ and the correct private key : $ed=1 \mod{\varphi(n)}$ and recover the plaintext by performing the usual decryption.
Here's the script with the assumed Key Generation : `
from Crypto.Util.number import *
nbits = 1024
p = getPrime(nbits)
q = getPrime(nbits)
n = p*q
e = 2**16 + 1
phi = (p+1)*(q+1)

message = b'CTF{testflag}'
m = bytes_to_long(message)
d = pow(e,-1,phi)
c = pow(m,e,n)

print(f'n = {n}') 
print(f'e = {e}')
print(f'phi = {phi}')
print(f'c = {c}')

The solution is :
from Crypto.Util.number import *

C = phi - n - 1
delta = C^2 - 4*1*n
p = int((C - sqrt(delta))/2*1)
q = int((C + sqrt(delta))/2*1)

assert p*q == n

d = pow(e,-1,(p-1)*(q-1))

m = pow(c,d,n)

print(f'The flag is : {long_to_bytes(int(m)).decode()}')

Hope this was clear.
